# ¿Cómo se usa condición where mismo campo varios valores?

Tags: sql-server

Buenas,

La pregunta es como filtro varias opciones en la misma columna con Where pero que no me devuelva tipo (OR) osea bien sea que exista una o la otra, necesito que existan las dos, sí o sí; algo así como usar la siguienta clausula:

WHERE DESCRIPCION = 'Endo' and DESCRIPCION = 'No Afiliado' 
(yo se que está mal decir que este campo sea igual a A y que sea igual que B al mismo tiempo, pero debe haber una manera)

WHERE DESCRIPCION IN ('Endo','No Afiliado') NO funciona porque me trae el uno o el otro o los dos, pero no aquel registro que cumple con las mismas condiciones.

Agrego una consulta temporal para mostrar lo que trato.

```
DECLARE @TMP TABLE (
        ID INT,
        OBJ_ID INT,
        DESCRIPCION  VARCHAR(50)
        )

INSERT INTO @TMP (ID, OBJ_ID, DESCRIPCION)
VALUES
(1, 223344, 'Afiliado 2016'),
(2, 223344, 'No Afiliado'),
(3, 223344, 'En Vacaciones'),
(4, 223344, 'No aplica'),
(5, 223344, 'Afiliado 2017'),
(6, 778899, 'Afiliado 2015'),
(7, 778899, 'No Afiliado'),
(8, 778899, 'En Vacaciones'),
(9, 778899, 'No aplica'),
(10, 778899, 'Cancelado por serv.'),
(11, 778899, 'Endo'),
(12, 778899, 'No Afiliado'),
(13, 778899, 'En Vacaciones'),
(14, 778899, 'No aplica'),
(15, 778899, 'Afiliado 2017'),
(16, 116655, 'No Afiliado'),
(17, 116655, 'En Vacaciones'),
(18, 116655, 'No aplica'),
(19, 116655, 'Endo'),
(20, 116655, 'Afiliado 2017')




SELECT *
FROM @tmp

SELECT *
FROM @tmp
WHERE DESCRIPCION IN ('Endo','No Afiliado')


 Resultado, no es lo que necesito
    ID  OBJ_ID  DESCRIPCION
-----------------------------
    2   223344  No Afiliado
    7   778899  No Afiliado
    11  778899  Endo
    12  778899  No Afiliado
    16  116655  No Afiliado
    19  116655  Endo

    Resultado esperado:
    ID  OBJ_ID  DESCRIPCION
    -----------------------      
    7   778899  No Afiliado
    16  116655  No Afiliado
```

Como se puede ver el OBJ_ID 223344 no me debe aparecer porque no tiene la Descripción = Endo

Comment: Por qué el resultado es sólo el ID 7 y no el 11 también, por ejemplo?

Comment: Como comentas no tiene sentido comprobar si un campo es igual a varios valores diferentes y, por ello, no existe un operador para hacerlo. Puedes hacerlo con un `AND` pero seguiría sin tener ningún sentido.

Comment: @Lamak por que así es como espero obtenerlos, supongo que con un group by se podría pero no es es caso de la pregunta.
@ AsierVillanueva pero necesito que solo me traiga aquellos que contengan el 'Endo' y el 'No Afiliado', porque? porque así me lo pidieron, debe existir alguna forma

Comment: @Vulpex mi pregunta va más relacionada con la lógica al respecto. Cómo eliges esa fila para el obj_id = 778899?

Comment: Eso es precisamente lo que quiero saber, ¿como obtengo ese resultado?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que nada te felicito por la forma en que presentaste la pregunta, el hecho de agregar un ejemplo reproducible, parece una obviedad pero hace la diferencia. 
Una forma de resolverlo es mediante una subconsulta para filtrar aquellos casos dónde `OBJ_ID` tenga las dos descripciones, seguramente hay formas más nuevas, pero al menos ésta es bastante compatible entre versiones de `sql-server`

```
SELECT  MAX(t.ID)   AS 'ID',
    t.OBJ_ID,
    t.DESCRIPCION
    FROM @tmp t
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  OBJ_ID
                FROM @tmp
                WHERE DESCRIPCION IN ('Endo','No Afiliado')
                GROUP BY OBJ_ID
                HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DESCRIPCION) > 1
        ) Casos
        ON Casos.OBJ_ID = t.OBJ_ID
    WHERE T.DESCRIPCION IN ('No Afiliado')
    GROUP BY t.OBJ_ID,
        t.DESCRIPCION
```

Una aclaración: El resultado es el Máximo ID de los OBJ_ID cuya descripción es 'No Afiliado'

La salida final es:

```
ID  OBJ_ID  DESCRIPCION
--  ------- -----------
16  116.655 No Afiliado
120 778.899 No Afiliado
```

Tal como menciona @Lamak la salida no es exactamente igual a la que solicitas

```
Resultado esperado:
ID  OBJ_ID  DESCRIPCION
-----------------------      
7   778899  No Afiliado
16  116655  No Afiliado
```

Por consiguiente entiendo que la solución de Kroneaux Schneider es mejor

Comment: Pero esto no entrega el resultado esperado....en el resultado puesto en la pregunta, se devuelven sólo 2 filas, por eso puse un comentario preguntando la lógica detrás de ese resultado

Comment: Ahí ya modifique la consulta que se parece más a lo que solicita el usuario. Gracias por el comentario

Comment: Sí, pero aún no entrega los resultados esperados por el op con los datos que de ejemplo que puso en la pregunta...

Comment: Si es justo lo que se pretende lograr, muchas gracias por su paciencia, ahora solo espero comprender que fue lo que se hizo en esta consulta.

Comment: @Vulpex *sigh*. Pero en tu resultado esperado es sólo una fila para el `OBJ_ID = 778899`, y con este resultado obtienes 2...pero bueno

Comment: No, obtengo 2, uno de cada uno [778899] y [116655]

Comment: Creo que no Lamak obtienes un registro por cada OBJ_ID lo que difiere es en el ID que te va a mostrar, de todas formas, no me gusta ms solución así como quedó, voy a editarla @Vulpex: aclara por favor que ID esperas obtener en cada caso.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho , En realidad el ID es indifirente lo importante es el objeto que cumpla con las dos o mas condiciones al mismo tiempo, ya con tu consulta o con la de Kroneaux voy a trabajar haber si la logro adaptar a la real.

Comment: Gracias por el crédito Patricio, pero si el OP considera que esa pequeña diferencia no es problema está bien que tengas la correcta ya que editaste 10 minutos antes que yo :D

Answer (score 3):

La primera que se me ocurre es que busques primero por una y sobre sus resultados busques la otra en un Where *"anidado"*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID = (SELECT TOP 1 TMP.ID FROM @tmp TMP WHERE TMP.OBJ_ID = [OUT].OBJ_ID AND TMP.DESCRIPCION = [OUT].DESCRIPCION), [OUT].OBJ_ID, [OUT].DESCRIPCION
  FROM @tmp [OUT]
 WHERE DESCRIPCION = 'No Afiliado' AND OBJ_ID IN (SELECT OBJ_ID
                                                FROM @tmp
                                               WHERE DESCRIPCION = 'Endo')
```

---

## Descripción

1. Primero se filtran los `OBJ_ID` que tienen 'Endo'
2. Sobre los resultados de esa consulta se buscan los que tengan 'No afiliado'.
3. Una vez encontrados los `OBJ_ID` que cumplen con ambas condiciones, el `ID` que mostrará será el primero (`TOP 1`) que tenga el `OBJ_ID` y cuya `descripción` sea la misma que en la condición del paso **2** (`No Afiliada`).
4. `DISTINCT` eliminará los resultados duplicados.

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene el mismo problema de entregar más filas de las solicitadas

Comment: Modifiqué la consulta, es algo más laboriosa pero me dio exactamente los resultados esperados.

Comment: En efecto entrega el resultado posteado por el op, y por eso retiro mi voto en contra. Pero aún no sabemos la lógica detrás de por qué el op eligió esos resultados

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que busca el renglón donde la descripción sea "No afiliado"; actualicé mi respuesta aclarando esto un poco.

Comment: No es solo eso, porque en los datos de ejemplo para el obj_id = 778899 hay 2 filas con valor "No Afiliado"

Comment: @Lamak, si es correcto y necesito omitir ese tipo de casos, porque es una tabla bastante rara que a mi pensar está mal diseñada y no debería tener que liarse uno buscando en la misma tabla varios where en la misma columna pero pasa y está pasando así.

Comment: @KroneauxSchneider, también esta funcional esta consulta, voy a investigar que fue lo que hiciste para comprender como se soluciona este tipo de casos. Muchas Gracias Compa, la marcaría como respuesta pero ya sabes no se puede, es totalmente válida.

Comment: No solo eso, de hecho la otra respuesta no da tu resultado esperado (`ID = 12` en lugar de `ID = 7`...). Y realmente son tres consultas, pero digamos que la que no está entre paréntesis es la que manda sobre las otras dos; `DISTINCT` trae resultados únicos.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo @Kroneaux Schneider, si es factible eliminar mi respuesta y que el OP vote la tuya no tengo problema

Comment: Las dos son factibles, ahora debo hacer que no solo sea 'Endo' y 'No Afiliado', sino ademas que sea igual a 'No aplica' y 'Cancelado por serv', pero pues voy a probar con cual de las dos obtengo mejores maneras de estos datos, porque además de este problema no se aplica a una sola tabla sino a 3 tablas y cada una tiene su condicional, asi que probaré creando vistas de cada una y luego unirlos o algo así.

Comment: @Vulpex edité mi respuesta para explicar un poco mejor lo que está sucediendo aquí. Y este es un excelente ejemplo de que en la programación no hay solo una respuesta correcta :D

Answer (score 1):

Veo que ya está resuelto tu problema, pero creo que no está de más agregar ésto, que puede optimizar consulta, hacerlo más compresible o ayudar a alguien más.

```
SELECT * FROM @TMP
WHERE OBJ_ID IN (SELECT OBJ_ID FROM @TMP WHERE DESCRIPCION="No Afiliado")
AND OBJ_ID IN (SELECT OBJ_ID FROM @TMP WHERE DESCRIPCION="Endo")
AND (DESCRIPCION = "No Afiliado" OR DESCRIPCION = "Endo")
GROUP BY OBJ_ID, DESCRIPCION
```

**OBJ_ID [778899]** debería mostrar 3 registros ya que tiene asignado 2 "No Afiliado". Pero por el GroupBy se muestran sólo 2

Comment: También es válida la consulta, me arroja los resultados esperados, muchas gracias, de seguro a alguien más le puede ayudar y también probaré con esta haber que resultados me arroja en real.

Answer (score 0):

para que una condición con el mismo campo pueda ser evaluada con dos o más diferentes valores, te puedes apoyar del operador IN 
tu consulta podría quedar de esta manera :

```
WHERE DESCRIPCION IN ('Endo','No Afiliado')
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola y bienvenido!! gracias por la respuesta!!! te aconsejo mirar el [tour] y tambien [answer].